# Android: Asynchronous Multiplayer games

Tags: android, game

My wife and I play [Ascension](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.playdekgames.android.Ascension) together fairly regularly, and we love the async multiplayer because we can take our turns during breaks and free time when we're nowhere near one another.

Recently, I've started looking for more games we can play this way, and I've had a hard time finding them. So I'm turning to you; and I'll make the question more general so that it's not just about me and my wife.

**What are some Android games which use asynchronous multiplayer?**

By `asynchronous multiplayer`, I mean that: `Games are turn-based, and players can take their turns any time, without needing the other player(s) online`

I have found a few, such as [Uniwar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.uniwar) and [Great Big War Game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rubicon.dev.gbwglite) -- I'm just looking to expand the list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [WarLight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.warlight&hl=en)?

It's just like good old [Risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_(game)); a turn-based strategy game where you send your troops off to take control of various territories. It is an asynchronous game, so you can take however long you want for your move. I also believe that you can access it online through a desktop browser or the like, so you can play across different devices.